# Is it possible to pour a monolithic concrete pit?

Tags: plumbing, concrete, construction

I'm pouring a concrete storm water pit over an existing pipe. This is basically a big box without a lid. Most jobs I've seen pour the base first, let it cure, and then place the wall forms on top and pour the walls. This avoids the risk of the wall concrete "flowing" through to the base and essentially self-levelling. But is it possible to do it in one (monolithic) pour?

My current plan is to pour the base with short form work, like pouring a small slab. Then the wall forms would be essentially two tubes, one inside the other. The outer one would connect into the base form work, and the inner one would be suspended inside the outer one, connected at the top. I would pour then the walls whilst the base concrete is still wet.

My only concern with this method is that when pouring the walls, the concrete will be pushed down into the base due to gravity, where nothing will stop it rising up so that the level of the base is the same as the top of the walls. Obviously this is not what I want as it will basically produce a concrete block rather than a box. But this depends on the viscosity of the concrete. I'm planning on using a standard 25 MPa 80mm slump mix. Will the concrete be viscous enough to prevent this from happening?

If this is a problem, I could either pour the base separately (which would be more work/time) or place a piece of plywood over the top of the base before pouring the walls to prevent it squeezing out (not ideal because I wouldn't get a nice finish on the base).

Drawing of the pit specifications for context: https://i.imgur.com/9AHcgYV.png

Internal depth is 900 mm. Internal footprint is 900x600.

Comment: You didn't name the wall height. I see that the thicknesses are 6" from the drawing.

Comment: @popham Edited to add depth. 900 mm or 36 inch.

Comment: Your piece of plywood over the base (under naive mechanical assumptions) would generate buoyancy forces equal to the volume of concrete displaced by your concrete cube's hollow core. With a semi-viscous fluid like your low slump concrete, that full buoyancy force doesn't show up, but if you're vibrating, there's certainly still substantial uplift.

Comment: Any particular reason you want to do this in one pour?

Comment: Concrete swimming pools are evidence that it could be done. Whether it's really the right answer for your case, I can't say.

Comment: Yup, a dry enough mix and no interior forms at all, (just lots of hard labor with a trowel while wearing funny shoes with spikes) as with swimming pool construction, is the way to do it, if you want to do it. But really, a "leak" in the bottom of a catch basin is just not something that matters,  (if the pipe works, the "leak" will help to remove groundwater to the pipe.)

Answer (score 2):

If you extend the sheathing from your inner wall forms all the way through the slab's thickness (with dowels for continuity across the joint), then you can abandon the part of the form sandwiched between the slab and the perimeter walls. Think sheet piles with the upper part removed after your concrete sets.

From Table M9.2-1 of [AWC's Manual for Engineered Wood Construction](https://awc.org/wp-content/uploads/2022/01/AWC-2018-Manual-1810.pdf) (page 52),
48/24 OSB's strong axis bending strength is 1000#-in/ft. Considering a 1ft wide strip at the bottom of your pour, that's 1000#-in. At that depth the concrete's pressure is (140#/ft^3)(3ft) = 420#/ft^2. Call it 840#/ft^2 for safety. A cantilever length of 6in (the thickness of your floor) for the 48/24 OSB implies a bending demand of

(840#/ft^2)(1ft)(6in)(1ft/12in)(6in)/2 = 1260#-in,

so the 48/24 OSB (with a strength of 1000#-in) is inadequate. That safety factor of 2 when amplifying the 420#/ft^2 to 840#/ft^2 actually comes from an document called ACI 347 for designing formwork, so I wouldn't relax it. A 6in cantilever, then, can't adequately support the concrete. Instead you could brace the cantilever tip with soil by burying it under 6 to 12 inches of compacted fill, or you could install tension ties to the outer form to brace the tip.

Answer (score 2):

> Most jobs I've seen pour the base first, let it cure, and then place the wall forms on top and pour the walls.

There's probably a *really* good reason for this, and I think you've identified it yourself.

If you go with your plywood lid issue, you'd have to put enough weight on the lid to resist the upward pressure of the concrete walls or your plywood would just float up. I can only imagine that the time spent finding this weight and the money/effort expended to procure it, place it, and remove it would far outweigh (pun intended) the time/money/effort required to make two separate pours.

*I do find it somewhat amusing that one of your concerns about the plywood lid idea is that you're worried about not getting a nice finish on the inside of a storm water pit that you'll only ever see the inside of again if there's a problem.*

Answer (score 1):

If you relax the monolithic constraint, then you can do it with one concrete truck. Place your bottom slab, and then add the proper amount of sugar to the remaining batch to retard it. Now you can wait for an hour or so for the bottom slab to set sufficiently, where now it's strong enough to contain the remaining wet concrete. There will be a cold joint where the walls intersect the base.

Comment: That's an interesting option, I hadn't thought of using a retarder. Unfortunately the concrete company charges a hefty overtime fee for anything beyond 25 minutes so not ideal, but I'll consider it. Cold joints are not a problem since that seems like the standard way of doing it.

Comment: I presume that this "sugar" isn't actual cane/beet sugar that one might eat if it weren't embedded in concrete, but a nickname for a chemical cure retardant that would be added to the concrete mix...

Comment: @FreeMan Yes actual, edible, refined white sugar. But there are risks to it -- too much sugar can prevent the concrete from setting, ie ruin it. I understand there also exist engineered admixtures that can suspend the wet concrete and others that can re-activate it, but I have no personal experience with those.

Comment: Huh... So sugar can seize your engine, slow your concrete cure, _and_ frost your flakes. Who knew?